# Binary search with file reading goes infinite loop

Tags: java, arrays, file, java.util.scanner, binary-search

I want to implement a binary search but the search key provided externally.That means I have a file in my hard disk. I want to read the key values from this file. I write down a code for this purpose. But the code goes to infinite loop.

Here is my code:

```
public class T5 {
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
    double arr[]= new double[]{86.0,12.0,55.0,90.0,77.0,22.0,25.0,33.0,45.0,20.0,23.0};
    int first=0;
    int last=(arr.length)-1;
    Scanner x= new Scanner(new File("D:\\Test_1.txt"));
    while(x.hasNext()){
        double a =x.nextDouble();
        while(first<=last){
            int mid=(first+last)/2;
            if(arr[mid]==a){
                System.out.println("Search successful");
            }
            if(arr[mid]<a){
                last=mid+1;
            }
            else{
                last=mid-1;
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

The Text_1.txt file I mention here it like that

86.0

25.0

30.0

18.0

90.0

88.0

70.0

87.0

55.0

The array arr[] that mentioned here is the value with which the key value will be compared. The arr[] consist of 86.0 and the file has 86.0 so the search successful. The file has 25.0 and the arr also have value 25.0. So again search successful. The file  has a value 30.0 but the arr[] does not have it. So the search unsuccessful.

This is the concept but why it is go to infinite loop. Any Suggestion and discussion most welcome.

Comment: first=mid+1, not last

Comment: Also it only works if the array (`arr`) is already sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, arrays you apply binary search to should be sorted!

You should always try to visualize your algorithms. For binary search specifically you have to imagine that you have 2 bounds left and right, the left bound moves to the right and right bound moves to the left and the process continues until they collide, or until you find your element.

It's obvious to me that you didn't even try to trace your algorithm...

Also, notice that you have one while loop inside of the other. And you never reset your first and last variables at the beginning of the first loop. This is wrong.

One last thing, prefer `first + (last - first) / 2` to `(last + first) / 2`. Because, `(last + first) / 2` can overflow, while `first + (last - first) / 2` can't.

Let's decompose your program into 2 functions, one will perform binary search and the other will read.

1)

```
static boolean binarySearch(double a) {
    double[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int first = 0;
    int last = arr.length - 1;

    while (first <= last) {
        int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] == a) {
            return true;
        } else if (arr[mid] < a) {
            first = mid + 1;
        } else /*if (arr[mid] > a)*/{
            last = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

2)

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        double d = sc.nextDouble();
        binarySearch(d);
    }
}
```

Also, there's a binarySearch method in the JDK, so your code becomes:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        double d = sc.nextDouble();
        Arrays.binarySearch(arr, d);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to use a unsorted array ,then which search algorithm is useful?

Comment: @Saswati binary search doesn't work with unsorted arrays. You have to sort, otherwise you'll get unexpected results. Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm .

Comment: I understand that binary search only work with sorted array. I want to know that if there any other searching algorithm which work well with unsorted array?

Comment: @Saswati 1) there's linear search, which is O(N).2) You can also put your elements into a HashSet<Double> set, and call set.contains(x), this works in O(1).